# Disabling package for certain file types in Sublime Text?

Tags: autocomplete, sublime-text-3

I've been using [TabNine](https://tabnine.com/) for autocompletion. It provides autocomplete for many languages. Now I'm trying out [Kite](https://kite.com) which autocompletes only Python.

If I didn't disable TabNine, then the TabNine suggestions would override Kite's. How do I disable TabNine for only *.py files?

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb. 2022, Tabnine does not support disabling specific languages.
It is a known issue: https://github.com/codota/tabnine-sublime/issues/67